# MVC3: Why Html.Action does not generate the expected URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I have a "Projects" controller and a "Dashboard" action which takes a parameter named "accountID".

```
 public ActionResult Dashboard(String accountID)
 {
     return View();
 }
```

I have a route defined as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProjectsHome",
    "{accountID}/projects",
    new { controller = "Projects", action = "Dashboard" }
);
```

The idea is to have an URL like /1111/projects  where 1111 represents the accountID. The URL will then execute the Dashboard action of the Projects controller.

The issue which I am facing is that   `@Html.ActionLink("Projects", "Dashboard", "Projects", new { accountID = "1111" }, null)` generates an URL like /Projects/Dashboard?accountID=1111 and I was expecting something like /1111/projects

My workaround is to use `@Url.RouteUrl("ProjectsHome", new { accountID = "1111"})`, but I was wondering why the Html.ActionLink does not pick the route I defined and formats the URL accordingly?

Another interesting fact is that in one of the controller's code I have something like  `return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Projects", new { accountID = newAccount.ID });` which builds the URL as I expected.

Note: I have no other routes defined except the generic "catch-all" one. I use ASP.NET MVC3.

Comment: Not sure exactly what happened but I cannot reproduce it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to replicate the result you're getting is by placing the "ProjectsHome" route **below** the generic "catch-all" route. When I had it placed above the generic route the ActionLink generated the URL in the form you wanted.

The MVC routing engine scans the route table until it finds one that it can match, meaning it can never reach a defined route that is after the catch-all.

Answer (score 0):

the map route needs to be defined like this -

routes.MapRoute(
    "ProjectsHome",
    "{accountID}/projects",
    new { controller = "Projects", action = "Dashboard", **accountID = UrlParameter.Optional** }
);

you missed to define the accountID in map route.